# Javascript using .filter on nested arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am hoping there is a way to use `.filter()` for a nested `array` to make things a little easier on the eyes.

Here is a basic example of what I want.

```
[
 {
  people: [
           {
            name: 'sam',
            id: 1
           }
           {
            name: 'john',
            id: 2
           }
          ]
 },
  people: [
           {
            name: 'marry',
            id: 1
           },
           {
            name: 'paul',
            id: 1
           }
          ]
 },
 ...
]
```

can I use `.filter` to get all the people with id of 1?

I can do it by using `.filter` with a

```
for(...){
   for(...){
   ...
   }
 ...
}
```

but I don't really want nested for loops as this will add unnecessary complexity.

Edit: I would like output to look like a single array of the nested people object

```
       [{
        name: 'sam',
        id: 1
       },
       {
        name: 'john',
        id: 1
       },
       {
        name: 'john',
        id: 1

      ]
```

Comment: Do you want to get a single, flat array of people? Can you post an example of the expected result?

Comment: "...all the people with id of 1" That's an interesting concept of an ID.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: For posterity, this is something called "flatmap": Given a list of values (in your case objects with property `person`), each value is *mapped* to a list (in your case each object is mapped to a filtered version of the array in `people`). Now you have a list of lists, which gets *flattened* into a single list.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I could call it `hooblyha` but I think we get the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter` and `Array#map`.

```js
var arr = [{people:[{name:'sam',id:1},{name:'john',id:2}]},{people:[{name:'marry',id:1},{name:'paul',id:1}]}],
    res = [].concat(...arr.map(v => v.people.filter(c => c.id == 1)));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped with out the looping.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Honestly speaking, `map` is still a loop, but you don't have to use `for`, though.

Comment: @Jonasw It will return a nested array. I just wanted to keep it flat (:

Comment: @Jonasw Sorry I should have been a little more specific, I just wanted a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` can certainly be part of the solution:

```
const people = [];
for (const obj of data) {
    people.push(...obj.people.filter(p => p.id === 1));
}
```

```js
const data = [
 {
  people: [
           {
            name: 'sam',
            id: 1
           },
           {
            name: 'john',
            id: 2
           }
          ]
 },
 {
  people: [
           {
            name: 'marry',
            id: 1
           },
           {
            name: 'paul',
            id: 1
           }
          ]
 }
];
const people = [];
for (const obj of data) {
    people.push(...obj.people.filter(p => p.id === 1));
}
console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

*(You could use `data.forEach` instead of the `for-of` loop if you prefer.)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ES5 approach with concatinating the filtered arrays.

```js
var array = [{ people: [{ name: 'sam', id: 1 }, { name: 'john', id: 2 }] }, { people: [{ name: 'marry', id: 1 }, { name: 'paul', id: 1 }] }],
    result = [].concat.apply([], array.map(function (a) {
        return a.people.filter(function (p) {
            return p.id === 1;
        });
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```